# If $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of open sets, are $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}X_n$ and $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}X_n$ open?

Tags: general-topology

The statement $$X_1, X_2 \text{ open} \Rightarrow X_1\cup X_2 \text{ and } X_1\cap X_2\text{ open}$$ can easily be proven. 
Now can that be adjusted to prove, that the union or intersection respectively of any number of open sets, will also be an open set?

My approach would be along the following (to prove that $\bigcap_{n \in\mathbb{N}}X_n$ is open):
$$\text{ trivial case: }  \bigcap_{n \in\mathbb{N}}X_n = \emptyset \Rightarrow \text{ Empty set is always open}$$
$$x \in\bigcap_{n \in\mathbb{N}}X_n \Rightarrow \exists r_i > 0:\; B_{r_i}(x) \subset X_i ,\quad \forall i\in\mathbb{N}$$ 
$$r' = \min(r_1 ... r_n) \Rightarrow B_{r'}(x) \subset B_{r_i}(x) \subset X_i, \quad \forall i \in\mathbb{N} \Rightarrow B_{r'}(x)\subset\bigcap_{n \in\mathbb{N}}X_n$$
$$\Rightarrow \bigcap_{n \in\mathbb{N}}X_n \text{ is open}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Conjunction* and *disjunction* are the wrong words: what you’re talking about are the *union* and *intersection* of the sets.)

Your argument shows that for any $m\in\Bbb N$, $\bigcap_{n=1}^mX_n$ is open — i.e., that the intersection of any **finite** number of open sets is open — but it does **not** show that $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}X_n$ is open. And in fact it is not at all difficult to find counterexamples. For example,let

$$X_n=\left(0,1+\frac1n\right)\;$$

each $X_n$ is an open set in $\Bbb R$, but $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}X_n=(0,1]$, which is not open: $1$ is in the set, but there is no $\epsilon>0$ such that the $\epsilon$-nbhd $(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$ of $1$ is contained in the intersection.

The problem is that while you can take the minimum of a finite set of positive radii, as you do when you let $r'=\min\{r_1,\ldots,r_n\}$, the infinite set $\{r_i:i\in\Bbb N\}$ of radii of the balls needed to get inside **all** of the sets $X_i$ need not have a minimum element, and its infimum (greatest lower bound) may be $0$. That’s what happens in my example above.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're dealing with metric spaces, so I'll write my answer based on that. Let $\{X_n\}_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ is a sequence of open sets. It's true that $\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb{N}} X_n$ is open, but it's **false** that $\bigcap_{n \in \Bbb{N}} X_n$ is always open.

For a counterexample of the second, let $X_n = \left(0,1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)$. Then $\bigcap_{n \in \Bbb{N}} X_n = (0,1]$ (can you prove this?), which is not open as no neighbourhoods of $1$ lies in the set.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite set of such $r_i$ (as far as I understand you take an infinite intersection), therefore you cannot choose a minimal one.
Take, for example, $X_n = (-\frac{1}{n}, 1+\frac{1}{n})$.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers provide good counter-examples, though I'll give a counter-example which is intuitive.

Define $X_n = (\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}), \forall \; n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Then $\bigcap\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}X_n = \{0\}$. This is left to you to prove. It's basic real analysis. The intuition is that you are getting arbitrarily close to zero from both sides of zero as $n \in \mathbb{N}$ increases. Convert this intuition into a formal proof.

$\{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ since $\{0\}^c = (-\infty, 0)\cup (0, \infty)$ is open.